# PHP Session lost after form

Tags: php, session, post

I'm new using PHP and I want to use sessions for login purposes but every time I submit a form, the session becomes null.

login.php:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])) 
{
    $email = $_SESSION['user'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   // css stuff
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />
<buttontype="submit" name="loginbtn">Ingresar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX:

```
function setSession()
{
    console.log('si');
    jQuery.ajax
    (
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/questionary",
            data: { user: jQuery("#email").val() },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function( data ) 
            {
                alert(data.user);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Data is send by POST and thats how I get $_POST['email']

questionary.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['email']; //this value is sent when the user logs in.
$session = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $_POST['email'];
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendFormBtn'])) 
{
  //do something...
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   // css stuff
</head>
<body>
 <section id="features">
  <button name="sendFormBtn" onclick="setSession()">Submit</button>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button to submit the form on page questionary, the session becomes null. Any idea why?

Comment: Content of `/questionary` is missing. Does it contain `session_start();` on top as well?

Comment: I made an edit to my post, questionary does have session_start();

Comment: You send email as user `user: jQuery("#email").val()`, but use `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['email'];`. You need to use `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];`

Comment: I think you’re dealing with more than one issue. Hold off on the sessions until you get the form working. You’re expecting json but I don’t see questionary.php returning anything other than html. You’re not even referencing login.php unless I missed it…